# How to save a changed value in Django admin on api creation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

In Django Admin I am displaying a url.
This url is created using the id the object that it is attached to.
I'm using python, django and django-rest-framework.
In my views I have logic on the ApiDetail class.  Here I override the 'get' method.
I increment the current object in views.py:

```
currentObject = Api.objects.get(id=pk)
currentObject.currentNumber += 1
currentObject.save()
return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In models.py I set the url field:

```
class Api(models.Model):
    myUrl = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name="Url", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formUrl = "https://custumUrl/"+str(self.id)+"/"        
        super(Api, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here I override the api save method to update the formUrl field.
The problem I have is when a form is first added to Django admin and saved the url says:

```
https://custumUrl/none/
```

It should say:

```
https://custumUrl/1/
```

Or any number, but definitely the number of the objects id.

Comment: Because you assign the url before you save the object, therefore before the ID is defined. But why do you want to save the URL as a field, rather than just providing a method to output it when necessary?

Comment: I need the URL as a field so I can display it in the ApiAdmin class.  **class ApiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)**  in admin.py.  **list_display = ('objectName', 'myUrl')**.  My User will be utilizing Django admin and giving out the urls for use on other sites.

Comment: Not true. You can show the results of methods in the admin [changelist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and as [readonly fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in the edit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Daniel is right in their comments and you should follow their advice.

But if you don't want to do that, then you should first save an object, then assign an id value to the url, then save it again:

```
class Api(models.Model):
    myUrl = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name="Url", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Api, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.formUrl = "https://custumUrl/"+str(self.id)+"/"        
        super(Api, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `currentNumber` defined in he `Api` class?

Also, in your `Api` class, you have `myUrl` defined, but in the save method it's `formUrl`.

Maybe try something like this:

```
class Api(models.Model):
    formUrl = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name="Url", editable=False)

    def save(self):
        """If this is the firsts time populate required details, otherwise update it."""
        if not self.id:
           latest_obj = Api.latest('id')
           this_id = latest_obj.id
           self.formUrl = "https://custumUrl/"+str(this_id)+"/"        
           super(Api, self).save()
        else:
           #Save it as is
           super(Api, self).save()
```